# Computing centre of mass of cone using a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $B$ be the cone of height $h$ and radius $R$, given by
$$ B = \left\{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : \frac{h}{R}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq z \leq h \right\}.$$
I need to find the centre of mass of $B$.

In order to solve this, I got from the intersection between both limits of $z$ that $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$. So that I put in cylindrical coordinates and decided that $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $r$ runs from $0$ to $\sqrt R$. But for $z$, if I choose $z$ using the limits from the question, I take $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ as the lower limit, and when I integrate it, I gets to $0$, since it will be $h - h$. Well, honestly, I don't know if I got it right. That's why I need help.

For the better understading of you guys, here's how I tried to solve.

[my-attempt-to-solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6MsR.jpg)

Comment: Could you please write down your triple integral? (In cylindrical coordinates, with all the limits.) I think you should be trying to integrate $\int_{r = 0}^{r = R} \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 2\pi} \int_{z = hr/R}^{z = h} z \ rdzd\theta dr. $  I don't see how you could have got $h - h$ by integrating this.

Comment: I got h-h when integrating with respect to z. I decided theta from 0 to 2*pi, r from 0 to sqrt(R) and z from (h/R)*sqrt(x^2+y^2) to h. But, integrating z and considering sqrt(x^2+y^2) = R, this R cancels with the R being divided by h. and it's just h in the lower limit. I don't know if I was clear. Anyway, that's it...

Comment: Look at the integral that I wrote down. That's the integral you want to be calculating. Note that the $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ that appears in your lower limit for $z$ should be replaced with $r$ (**not** with $R$). In other words, $h\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}/R$ is $hr/R$, **not** $h$.

Comment: Also, $r$ should go from $0$ to $R$, and **not** from $0$ to $\sqrt{R}$.

Comment: Now I see! Thanks a lot! Now I think I solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your work the limits of integration should be: for $r$  from $0$ to $R$, and  for $z$ from $hr/R$ to $h$. However, I think that computations are easier if we integrate by sections: for $0\leq z\leq h$, let
$$S_z=\left\{(x,y,z): \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{Rz}{h}\right\}$$
then its area is $|S_z|=\frac{\pi R^2z^2}{h^2}$ ($S_z$ is a disc).
Then assuming that the cone is a homogeneous solid, we have that
$$M=\int_{z=0}^h(\int_{S_z} dxdy)dz=\int_{0}^h|S_z|dz=\frac{\pi R^2}{h^2}\int_{0}^hz^2dz=\frac{\pi R^2h}{3}.$$
Therefore
$$\overline{z}=\frac{1}{M}\int_{z=0}^hz(\int_{S_z}dxdy)dz=
\frac{1}{M}\int_{0}^hz|S_z|dz=\frac{3}{h^3} \int_{0}^hz^3 dz=\frac{3h}{4}.
$$